# vim remap specifics keys can't be remapped

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I'm getting a strange behavior, when I'm trying to remap key it does have any effect, from my testing it's only for the "numbers" keyboard keys which doesn't work as so far any other remap works properly.

```
noremap « <
noremap » >
```

I have tried saving it in my .vimrc, in the buffer using

```
:map « <
map » >
inoremap « <
inoremap » >
```

When I hit the first key it does write down the second one…
To give a bit more details I'm running a Debian with the "Bépo" layout (Dvorak-fr).

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Matth.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The mapping I'm setting up in my vimrc is not working for my some keyboard keys and i don't understand why.

Comment: Are you able to type and see those printed characters in console screen?

Comment: Yes, without any issues this where it get strange